# Obtaining CFGs for individual functions with evm-cfg-builder

Tags: solidity, evm, bytecode

I am trying to obtain a Control Flow Graph (CFG) of each individual function in a Solidity contract for Machine Learning analysis purposes.

I tried using evm-cfg-builder available at https://github.com/crytic/evm_cfg_builder to obtain CFGs for individual functions from a solidity contract. I had generated the running bytecode for the contract with

> solc --bin-runtime <contract.sol> -o runbytecode

Which generated a few bin-runtime files as my solidity contract contains a few codes within it. Afterwards, I used the following code to try and read from all these files and collect all the functions.

```
import os
from evm_cfg_builder.cfg import CFG

bytecode_folder = "/bytecode"
bytecode_files = [f for f in os.listdir(bytecode_folder) if f.endswith("bin-runtime")]

all_functions = []

for bytecode_file in bytecode_files:
    bytecode_path = os.path.join(bytecode_folder, bytecode_file)
    # Check if the file size is greater than 0
    if os.path.getsize(bytecode_path) > 0:
        with open(bytecode_path, encoding="utf-8") as f:
            runtime_bytecode = f.read()

        cfg = CFG(runtime_bytecode)

        for function in cfg.functions:
            all_functions.append(function)

print(len(all_functions))
for function in sorted(all_functions, key=lambda x: x.start_addr):
    print(f"Function {function.name}")
```

However, my output does not match the functions that are present in my contract. My list had a length of 28, when I only have a total of 22 functions in my contract. Additionally, there was a lot of "dispatcher", "owner" and "fallback" functions, which were not present in the contract's source code. Would greatly appreciate any help or any suggestions for alternative tools!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CFG doesn't present the internal functions and external calls. Maybe you can try use the cfg.output_to_dot to generate dot file for each function.